# OAuth 2.0 Verified desktop application login issues

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, desktop-application

Our desktop software was verified by Google recently. It uses the Google Drive API to gain access to the Google Drive.

From the last couple of days, users are **facing problem granting access of their Google Drive to our application**. The OAuth login screen is either freezing the ALLOW button or displaying a message,

> "You are trying to sign in from a browser or app that doesn't allow to
>   keep your account secure."

[image]

Comment: I think this is off-topic

Comment: Which software ? Which Language ? Can you provide your code ? Otherwise this question is off-topic